# UpdateObject of Wcf data service Entities

Tags: wcf-data-services

i have Prices and PriceGroup entities and i want to update both entities at same time like this:
    DataContext.AddObject("Prices/PriceGroup", oEditPrices);
    DataContext.UpdateObject(oEditPrices);
    DataContext.SaveChanges();

```
giving me error

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code></code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">The request URI is not valid. Since the segment 'Prices' refers to a collection, this must be the last segment in the request URI. All intermediate segments must refer to a single resource.</message>
</error>
```

Comment: Could you please grab an HTTP trace and post it here? Use for example Fiddler.

Comment: problem only updating Prices/PriceGroup two entities at a time, so i want to know what is best way to update two entities with one object as above..

Answer (score 0):

The AddObject first parameter must be a name of an entity set. So no slashes in it (I know the API doesn't validate, which it should, unfortunately). That's probably the reason why it fails (although I can't validate without the HTTP trace).

If you call AddObject you don't need to call UpdateObject on the same instance, it will have no effect.

If the goal is to add a new object and associate it with existing object, you can call AddRelatedObject. In the above case it would be something like:

DataContext.AddRelatedObject(existingPriceObject, "PriceGroup", newPriceGroup);
DataContext.SaveChanges();

If you need this to be performed as one operation (kind of like a transaction) you can pass in the Batch option to the SaveChanges call.